# printf in bash sometimes prints new line, can't figure out why

Tags: bash, printf, newline

if i have a file with below contents:

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3
8.8.8.8
127.0.0.4
```

and run this command to quickly test SSH connection success or failure:

```
while read host
do
 ssh -n -q -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 $host "echo 2>&1" && \
 printf "%-15s%-45s%s" `id -un` $host "SSH_OK" || \
 printf "%-15s%-45s%s" `id -un` $host "SSH_BAD"
done <host_list
```

I get:

```
myname   127.0.0.1                                    SSH_OK
myname   127.0.0.2                                    SSH_OK
myname   127.0.0.3                                    SSH_OKmyname   8.8.8.8                                      SSH_BAD
myname   127.0.0.4                                    SSH_OK[myname@server ~]$
```

As you can see, it looks nasty because it doesn't print a newine for the SSH_BAD output or the last line so bash prompt is tagged to end of last check.

I can fix this by adding a `\n` to the prinf but then i have double spaces on everything except for the BAD line.

Can someone tell me please where is printf getting the newline from when i don't specify one, and why it prints one for the SSH_OK lines but not the SSH_BAD lines.

Is there a good/easy way to fix this?

thank you 
fLo

Comment: The newline is coming from the `echo 2>&1`. That prints a newline when the `ssh` is successful, but doesn't do anything when `ssh` fails.

Comment: I don't think you are interpreting the output correctly (though I can't quite come up with a correct interpretation). But the newlines clearly aren't being printed at the *end* of the SSH_OK output lines or you wouldn't see this behaviour. They appear to be being printed at the *beginning* of the SSH_OK lines and not the SSH_BAD lines.

Comment: And @Barmar has just given me the piece I was missing. So, as I said, the newline is being printed *before* SSH_OK output lines and not being printed before SSH_BAD lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newlines are coming from `echo 2>&1` that you're running on the remote system. When the `ssh` is successful, this command executes, and you get a newline printed before the `printf`. When the `ssh` fails, the command doesn't run, so you get no newline before the `printf`.

I suggest you use a command that doesn't display anything, and then put `\n` in both `printf` lines:

```
while read host
do
 ssh -n -q -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 $host "true" && \
 printf "%-15s%-45s%s\n" `id -un` $host "SSH_OK" || \
 printf "%-15s%-45s%s\n" `id -un` $host "SSH_BAD"
done <host_list
```

Comment: +1 for the catch but you probably don't need `2>&1` for the `true` command. If you want to catch and strip all potential output, you could probably do `true >/dev/null 2>&1`.